# Add validation rule in yup based on external condition

Tags: vue.js, validation, yup

I'm trying to add a condition based on a prop passed to VueJS object.

I goggled some solutions, they all revolves around using `.when`. But, `.when` is used when you need to put a condition based on another field in the form.

In my case I need to form a shape based on a variable.

What I found and tried:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  FirstField: yup.string().required(),
  SecondFiled: yup.string().required(),
  ConditionalField: yup.string()
      .when([], {
        is: () => condition === true,
        then: yup.string().nullable(),
        otherwise: yup.string().required('Please input str2'),
      }),
})
```

This doesn't work: TS complains

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(keys: string | string[], builder: ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>): StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">', gave the following error.     Argument of type '{ is: () => boolean; then: yup.StringSchema<string | null | undefined, yup.AnyObject, undefined, "">; otherwise: yup.StringSchema<string, yup.AnyObject, undefined, "">; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'is' does not exist in type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.
```

Now, when I tried to make it simple, by adding a rule on an object, I still got TS errors.

This is a real example:

```
const rules = {
  signedAt: yup.string().required('...'),
  startsAt: yup.string().required('...'),
  endsAt: yup.string().required('...')
}

if (props.documentSet && !props.documentSet.regime) {
  rules.acceptancePlaces = yup.array(yup.string())
      .required('...')
      .min(1, '...');
}
```

TS complains:

```
TS2339: Property 'acceptancePlaces' does not exist on type '{ signedAt: StringSchema ; startsAt: StringSchema ; endsAt: StringSchema...>; }'
```

Then I asked ChatGPT and got this:

```
const rules: Partial<{
  signedAt: yup.StringSchema,
  startsAt: yup.StringSchema,
  endsAt: yup.StringSchema,
  acceptancePlaces?: yup.ArraySchema<yup.AnySchema> // Define the generic type
}> = {
  signedAt: yup.string().required('...'),
  startsAt: yup.string().required('...'),
  endsAt: yup.string().required('...'),
};

if (!props.documentSet.regime) {
  rules.acceptancePlaces = yup.array(yup.string()) // Specify the schema for the array items
      .required('...')
      .min(1, '...');
}
```

And again, TS complains

```
TS2707: Generic type 'ArraySchema ' requires between 2 and 4 type arguments.
```

It feels like I'm doing something completely wrong.

Imagine I have just two inputs in my form.

One is displayed conditionally, thus, the rule for the form should be added conditionally too.

Like, firstName and secondName. In some cases secondName input might not be present. So, the schema should not contain it. Sometimes it should.

How to achieve this? Preferably so that TS didn't have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you need to use `when` and pass a `ConditionBuilder` as the parameter and the builder accepts 2 parameters an empty array (which means an external dependency) and the `schema` of the current field.
make sure you have the latest version of `yup` installed. the version used in this example `"yup": "^1.2.0"`

example:

```js
const rules = yup.object().shape({
  signedAt: yup.string().required('field is required'),
  startsAt: yup.string().required('field is required'),
  endsAt: yup.string().required('field is required'),
  acceptancePlaces: yup.array(yup.string()).when(([], schema) => {
  //your condition here
    if (condition) {
      return schema.min(1).required();
    }

    return schema.notRequired();
  }),
});
```

and here is a complete working code:

`RulesComp.vue:`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as yup from "yup";
import {ref} from "vue";

const {documentSet} = defineProps<{
  documentSet: {
    regime: boolean
  }
}>()
const errorMessage = ref('');

const rules = yup.object().shape({
  signedAt: yup.string().required('field is required'),
  startsAt: yup.string().required('field is required'),
  endsAt: yup.string().required('field is required'),
  acceptancePlaces: yup.array(yup.string()).when(([], schema) => {
    if (documentSet.regime) {
      return schema.min(1).required();
    }

    return schema.notRequired();
  }),
});

const validateRules = async () => {
  await rules.validate({
    signedAt: 'signedAt',
    startsAt: 'startsAt',
    endsAt: 'endsAt',
  }).then(() => {
    errorMessage.value = '';
  }).catch((e) => {
    errorMessage.value = e.message;
  });
};
</script>

<template>
  <div :style="{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: '20px',
  }">
    <button type="button" @click="validateRules()">validate</button>
    <p v-if="errorMessage">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

`App.vue:`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import RulesComp from './components/RulesComp.vue'
import {reactive} from "vue";

const documentSet = reactive({
  regime: false,
});
const toggleRegime = () => {
  documentSet.regime = !documentSet.regime;
};
</script>

<template>
  <RulesComp :documentSet="documentSet"/>
  <button @click="toggleRegime()">
    toggle Regime
  </button>
  <p>
    {{JSON.stringify(documentSet)}}
  </p>
</template>
```

[image]